# Open URL in Firefox for Android using Intent

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, android-intent, intentfilter

Normally, we can open a URL in [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) using this intent:

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("googlechrome://navigate?url=http://google.com")))
```

But, how do I can achieve the same thing with [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox)? Is there something like `firefox://navigate?url`?

Comment: Which Firefox for Android? There are several. I doubt that Mozilla is using a custom scheme like this, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare This https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox","org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
 this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox","org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: This is just a copy-paste of the accepted answer. Even the original unedited version is essentially the same.